# convert String into time format in java

Tags: java, string

I am getting a String from front-end which I don't know exactly how it looks like - depending on the user. So it can be

> 23 or 234 or 23:34 or 00:32

In this case, the problem is **23** and **234** because I need a format like hhh:mm.
How can I do this in a performant way to always format the string in this format **[h]hh:mm**

Comment: the amount of hours can be two digets or three digest.

Comment: post the code you are tried

Comment: There can be 3 digit hours? Does 234 in the question mean 0234 (02:34 AM)

Comment: no, 234 hours means 234 hours and 0 minutes - so 234:00 [hhh:mm]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's all I got from the question

```
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String in = scn.nextLine();
    String time="";
    if(in.length()<=3)//23 or 234
    {
        time += in+":00";
    }
    else//23:34 or 00:32
    {
        time += in;
    }
    System.out.println(time);
```